# Why is my effect called twice?

Tags: purescript

I have the following programm written with `Eff`s and `Aff`s. Which runs as expected. That is it prints out the given `Int` and it does an asynchronous computation.

```
type JsonResponse = AffjaxResponse Json
access :: forall e m. Aff (ajax :: AJAX | e) (Either Error JsonResponse)
access = attempt $ get "http://localhost:8080/livesys/Robert"

staging :: forall e. Int -> Eff (console :: CONSOLE | e) Int
staging i = do
    liftEff $ log $ ">>" ++ show i
    return i

main :: forall a. Int -> Aff (ajax :: AJAX, console :: CONSOLE| a) Int
main state = do
    s <- liftEff $ staging state
    a <- liftAff access
    return s
```

If I change however the order of calls within `main` then something mysterious happens:

```
main :: forall a. Int -> Aff (ajax :: AJAX, console :: CONSOLE| a) Int
main state = do
    a <- liftAff access
    s <- liftEff $ staging state
    return s
```

the function `staging` is now being called **twice**! Wut?

Can anybody explain this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What happens if you remove the call to `liftAff` in `main`? I don't think it's necessary. (Not to excuse this behaviour, which does certainly seem wrong; I'm just trying to diagnose)

Comment: no change. The only thing that is sort of "exotic" is that I am using https://github.com/sectore/purescript-webpack-vanilla-hmr. Nevertheless it should behave consistently (either always 2 times or always once but not different on different orders)

Comment: Agreed. Can you run the above program through `psc-bundle` and upload it to a pastebin?

Comment: will need some time to extract only the barebone stuff without the D3 and Pux deps. On the weekend

Comment: You shouldn't need to, `psc-bundle` should remove all the dead code.

Comment: Why does `main` have that type and not `Eff _ _`?

Comment: @PhilFreeman because than I get an `main :: forall a. Int -> Eff (ajax :: AJAX, console :: CONSOLE| a) Int
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  No type class instance was found for Control.Monad.Aff.Class.MonadAff ( ajax :: AJAX | _0 ) (Eff ( ajax :: AJAX, console :: CONSOLE | a0 ) )
The instance head contains unknown type variables. Consider adding a type annotation. in value declaration main`

Comment: So you need to use something to turn `Aff` back into `Eff`, like `launchAff`.

Comment: @PhilFreeman its not so much to have a workaround. But simply the question WHY? why is this called twice. That is weird

Comment: No, I'm saying you should expect unpredictable results if the type of main is not what is expected by Pulp or psc-bundle. Unless you're running main some other way.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a case where an exception is being thrown rather than handled by the error function in an Aff instance. This leads to duplicate calls of the success function when used in conjunction with `attempt`.

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Data.Either (Either(..))
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (log)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Exception (Error, EXCEPTION, throwException, error)
import Control.Monad.Aff (Aff, makeAff, liftEff', launchAff, attempt)

raise = throwException <<< error


myAff :: forall e. Aff e String
myAff = _unsafeInterleaveAff $ makeAff doIt
  where
    doIt _ success = do
      log "operation"
      raise "it's dead jim" 
      success "done"

main = do
  launchAff $ do
    liftEff' $ log "start"
    myAff

foreign import _unsafeInterleaveAff :: forall e1 e2 a. Aff e1 a -> Aff e2 a
```

This code leads to the `doIt` being called twice, but when the Aff calls are reversed will not.

Additional:

Though this functionality does seem a little strange. Maybe replace `attempt` with some more like this?

```
exports._attempt = function (Left, Right, aff) {
  return function(success, error) {
    var affCompleted = false;
    try {
      return aff(function(v) {
        affCompleted = true
        success(Right(v));
      }, function(e) {
        affCompleted = true
        success(Left(e));
      });
    } catch (err) {
      if (affCompleted) {
        throw err;
      } else {
        success(Left(err));
      }
    }
  };
}
```